# Tablenames in sqlite Result

Tags: sqlite, gambas

Hy
I wrote an Application with Gambas uning SQLite

When I try to port to another Linux Ditro, I have different keys for the fields in the resultset for the SQLite Result

For example:

```
sqlect * from table
```

In on resultset I get

```
res["Tablename.Column1"] = Value
res["Tablename.Column2"] = Value
res["Tablename.Column3"] = Value
```

and In onther it is

```
res["Column1"] = Value
res["Column2"] = Value
res["Column3"] = Value
```

this is a big problem for me.
Any Ideas ?

Comment: Maybe using alias names would result in both systems in the same names without table qualifier: `select column1 as column1, column2 as column2, column3 as column3 from table`.

Comment: I can not modify every query in this big finished application.
I want to know why there is this difference in sqlite.

I also could write 

     select table.colum1, table.column2,table.colum3 from table

BUT:
I can not modify every query in this big finished application.

Comment: It may be a different SQLite version. You see, the column names in the result shall be unique so you can access the columns by name. One SQLite version may make sure by combining table and column, whereas the other version notices that only one table is involved and omits the table qualifier in the results.

Comment: Of course I checked SQLite Versions very first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a very long journey I found it:
I have to call

```
PRAGMA short_column_names = OFF
```

Very detailed Information can be found here:

https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_full_column_names

Comment: Great you found the solution and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_name.html) says:

> The name of a result column is the value of the "AS" clause for that column, if there is an AS clause. If there is no AS clause then the name of the column is unspecified and may change from one release of SQLite to the next.

So the only reliable way of getting consistent result column names is to use AS.

Comment: That is clear.
But the question was. Why is there a difference if there is not an AS from one distro to another by exactly the same release